# factory pattern in node.js (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, design-patterns

I was studying design pattern and my favourite is factory pattern. But when I dig more codes written by others I don't see this pattern occur that often, especially on the newer stack.

For instance in this article http://dealwithjs.io/design-patterns-the-factory-pattern-in-javascript/ the sample look like this:

```
function SimpleFactory(name) {  
    var factoryName = name;

    var getSalesEmployee = function(firstName, lastName) {
        return {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            comission: 0,
            salary: 100,
            projects: [],
            type: 'sales'
        };
    }

    var getEngineerEmployee = function(firstName, lastName) {
        return {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            salary: 150,
            manager: '',
            technologies: [],
            projects: [],
            type: 'engineer'
        }
    }

    var getName = function() {
        return factoryName;
    }

    return {
        getSales: getSalesEmployee,
        getEngineer: getEngineerEmployee,
        getName: getName
    }
}

module.exports = {  
    getInstance: SimpleFactory
}
```

Above code for me is controller, but usually I just write it like this

```
modue.exports = {

funcA = () => {}
funcB = () => {}

}
```

and in another file I can just use something.funcA, why do I still need to use factory here? I think commonJs of node just solved the leaking problem.

Comment: It's not actually required. You can to something like `module.exports = SimpleFactory` and then when you required it `var SimpleFactory = require('./factoryModule'); SimpleFactory.getEngineerEmployee()`

Answer (score 1):

Design pattern factory: [See More](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method)

In Nodejs + [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition), We use "Class" to write it.

**Example:** I don't write required in here. You need add it.

```
class ImageReader {
    constructor() {}
    getDecodeImage($param){};
}

class DecodedImage {
    constructor(image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    toString() {
        return `${this.image}: is decoded`;
    }
}

class GifReader extends ImageReader {
    constructor(image) {
        super();
        this.decodedImage = new DecodedImage(image);
    }

    getDecodeImage() {
        return this.decodedImage;
    }
}

class JpegReader extends ImageReader {
    constructor() {
        super(image);
        this.decodedImage = new DecodedImage(image);
    }

    getDecodeImage() {
        return this.decodedImage;
    }
}

class FactoryMethodDemo {
    main(args = []) {
        let reader = '';
        let image = args[0];
        let format = image.substring(image.indexOf('.') + 1, (image.length));
        if (format.equals("gif")) {
            reader = new GifReader(image);
        }
        if (format.equals("jpeg")) {
            reader = new JpegReader(image);
        }
        if (reader) {
            decodedImage = reader.getDecodeImage();
            console.log(decodedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Help it will help you.